# Why might Date.prototype.toString() and Date.prototype.toLocaleString() return strings representing inconsistent points in time?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, timezone, v8

```
var d = new Date();

// returns correct value "Fri Sep 26 2014 01:16:31 GMT+0300 (E. Europe Daylight Time)"
d.toString();

// returns incorrect value one hour behind "9/26/2014 12:16:31 AM"
d.toLocaleString();
```

It seems toLocaleString() is not taking DST into account for this test case.

How are local times calculated by Date (eg, does Chrome apply DST rules itself or via OS) and how/why does the algorithm differ between toString() and toLocaleString()?

Is this a bug or intended behavior?

Tested on Chrome/37.0.2062.120 with location Nicosia, Cyprus (http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/cyprus/nicosia)

Comment: It's all explained in great detail in [*ECMA-262 §15.9*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1). Of course, how browsers choose to implement both methods is entirely implementation dependant, but they should account for daylight saving based on system settings. I imagine that if you are actually in eastern Europe, a date formatted as m/d/y would be confusing and inconsistent with that location.

Comment: @RobG - that does explain much of what is asked, and [while it includes a serious flaw](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/06/07/javascript-date-type-is-horribly-broken/) - that doesn't account for the discrepancy demonstrated here.

Comment: Can you tell us what OS you are running on, and what is returned by a call to `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`

Comment: @MattJohnson—no, it doesn't, which is why it's a comment not an answer. ;-). There are flaws in how Date works in most browsers. Try `new Date('52-02').toLocaleString()` in Safari and check the time.

Comment: @RobG - :)  I'll have to check that one next time I'm on a Mac, but yes - I know what you mean.  :)

Comment: @RobG The user is in eastern Europe. The results are from a test page I created explicitly to test those two methods. I imagine their language setting in Chrome is set to en-US.

Comment: @MattJohnson Windows 7 x64 Enterprise. I'll find out about `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`

Comment: Ok, then also please find out what their time zone setting is in the Windows date/time control panel, or from `tzutil /g` on the command prompt.  My guess is that this is related to [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/v8-i18n/issues/detail?id=33)

Comment: Also note that `"(E. Europe Daylight Time)"` is not what I would expect.  A user in Cyprus with correct time zone settings should say either `"(GTB Standard Time)"` or `"(GTB Daylight Time)"` on Chrome in Windows.  That assumes the OS is set to `"GTB Standard Time"`, which has an English display name of `"(UTC+02:00) Athens, Bucharest"`

Comment: @Hans— *toLocaleString* might be getting confused given other settings are inconsistent with what might be expected for that timezone. No excuse for getting it wrong but something to check, try other locations that aren't where you are.

Comment: Also make sure you fully shut down and restart Chrome when changing the system time zone.  (Chrome doesn't properly pick up time zone change notifications from Windows.)

Comment: @MattJohnson—that seems to be a clue. Changing the timezone doesn't affect *toLocaleString*, it's still in the original timezone (which is displayed as "(EEST)") even though *date.torString* is per system settings. Restarting the browser fixes that. *toLocaleString* also continues to use US formatted date strings for both methods even though my system is not set for them. I have never trusted *toLocaleString*, much better to use an unambiguous format.

Comment: @RobG - personally, I don't trust any of JavaScript's formatting options.  I always go with [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a hunch, I tried changing my Windows time zone to:

```
TZ Key / ID:  "E. Europe Standard Time" 
Display name: "(UTC+02:00) E. Europe"
```

After restarting Chrome, I was then able to get the same thing you showed:

[image: Screenshot]

Taking a closer look, at the localization properties:

[image: Screenshot]

So it would seem that there is no time zone understood by Chrome.  This is because Chrome uses [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/), which uses the [CLDR mappings](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml) for Windows time zones.  That particular time zone is now considered "unmappable" - as there is no IANA time zone identifier that matches this Windows zone.

Note that this zone *used* to be mapped to `Asia/Nicosia`, but it was changed in the last revision of CLDR, as described in [CLDR #6973](http://unicode.org/cldr/trac/ticket/6973)

The reason for the discrepancy is that the `toLocaleString` function uses the [ECMAScript Internationalization API](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/index.html), while `toString` does not.  The prior is dependent on ICU and CLDR, while the latter just asks the OS for a time zone string.

The fix is for the user to switch their time zone to the correct setting.  For Cyprus, it should be:

```
TZ Key / ID:  "GTB Standard Time" 
Display name: "(UTC+02:00) Athens, Bucharest"
```

When looking at the options in the Windows Time Zone Control Panel:
[image: tz settings]

Be sure to close all Chrome windows completely after making the time zone change, as Chrome will not properly initialize time zones until it is restarted.

Now, the [issue I mentioned earlier](https://code.google.com/p/v8-i18n/issues/detail?id=33) in comments is still a problem, as `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` now returns `Europe/Kiev`, and it should return either `Asia/Nicosia`, or `Europe/Bucharest`.  But it is good enough to return the correct value for `toLocaleString` - at least most of the time.

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you! My initial thinking was to replace `toLocaleString()` with `moment().format()`. Easy enough and fixes the issue for other potentially affected users. I will also suggest to the user to correct their Windows time zone as an immediate solution as per your suggestion. Thanks again for the insights, Matt. Having a comprehensive explanation for this is extremely satisfying.

Comment: FWIW, user's reported original settings and observations are consistent with your test. Fix confirmed. Also, their Chrome default lang is set to en-US.